# One group of filters applying to the whole page and another group to one section of dashboard, what should be hierarchy and positioning of filters?

Tags: filter, data-tables, dashboard, analytics

I am working on a product that has an overview page - where users can find two sections statistics and a data table.

At the top of the hierarchy, we display the date and 'partner' filters that apply to both sections, statistics, and data tables.

Exclusively for the data table, we have a filter icon that opens the drawer for multiple filters, that only apply to the table.

The problem that was raised: Filters don't have one common place - we have two separate places for filtering; Another issue is that filters that are applied to the whole page will increase in number (now there are only two - displayed straight on the page without hiding in drawer).

Is there any way to put every filter in one drawer - I tried this but had to explicitly state which group of filters apply to which section. I also tried a solution to filter columns of the data table individually - but since data inside the table is related - having one place to filter everything makes much more sense.

What other solutions can I consider?
[image: Wireframe of a dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

Your design as it stands is correct. It's okay that "[f]ilters don't have one common place - we have two separate places for filtering" - you're communicating with the user that the top-of-page filters apply to the whole page, and the filters on cards only apply to the elements on their cards. What you'll want to avoid is duplication, having something like Date in both the page level and card level filters.

If your page-level filters start getting crowded, you could use the filter icon pattern you have at your card-level to hide the less-used criteria, and let the user open them in a drawer.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. That's what I was thinking - the current solution is the best. But another problem pops up - we can use the filter icon pattern again if filters grow in number - but what about applied filters visibility - Currently we use chips for data table applied filters - but the date and partner are just visible inside the fields. Is it okay to display chips at the top and also inside of data table section? Wouldn't it take to much vertical space and cluster the dashboard a lot?

Comment: Chips are good if the user needs to interact further with the filters - they're easy to dismiss/remove. If that's not the case, you could show a simple way to let the user know that filters are applied. VRBO.com, for example, makes the Filters button active, and shows how many filters are applied in parentheses. It might take a little time and testing with users to reach an optimal display state. You're heading in the right direction, though.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!